# Function to use all factor levels in a plot when none are specified

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

This question is similar to another question I asked today but it seemed different enough to merit a separate question. Please let me know if this thinking is erroneous. I have written a function that has an input for a factor level.

What I would like to do is modify my function so that when no factor level is specified, all factor levels are used. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
plotfunc <- function(Data, x, y,Species.Name){
  DataS <- Data %>% filter(Species %in% Species.Name)
  print(
    ggplot(DataS, aes_q(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~Species)
   )
}
```

Call the function with 1 factor level:

```
plotfunc(Data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length,Species.Name=c('versicolor'))
```

Or even call it with two:

```
plotfunc(Data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length,Species.Name=c('versicolor','virginica'))
```

The desired behaviour is something like this that utilizes all factor levels:

```
plotfunc(Data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is very specific to the `iris` data, but you can use the following:

```
plotfunc <- function(Data, x, y,Species.Name=NULL){
  if(is.null(Species.Name)) Species.Name = unique(Data$Species)
  DataS <- Data %>% filter(Species %in% Species.Name)
  print(
    ggplot(DataS, aes_q(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~Species)
  )
}
```

The key is to set the variable to `NULL` then check if it's `NULL` at the beginning.

**Update:**

For a more generic function, you just need to find a way to remove those things that are specific to the `iris` data.  Here I added a variable called `group.col` which says which column to use for grouping:

```
plotfunc <- function(Data, x, y, group.col, groups=NULL){
  if(is.null(groups)) groups = unique(Data[,group.col])
  DataS <- Data[Data[,group.col] %in% groups,]
  print(
    ggplot(DataS, aes_q(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))) + 
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~Species)
  )
}
plotfunc(Data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, group.col=5)
plotfunc(Data=iris, x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, group.col=5, groups=c('versicolor'))
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to make the function more generic? So that is how do you specify the factor column name in the function call so that this is more broadly applicable.